# Definite integral $\int_0^1 \ln^2(x)\ln^2(1-x)dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms

How can we calculate $\int_0^1\ln^2(x)\ln^2(1-x)dx$?

I have solved $\int_0^1\ln^{m}(x)\ln(1-x)dx$ but can't solve the above integral.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Comment: Is $\ln^2(\cdot) = \ln(\ln(\cdot))$ or $(\ln(\cdot))^2$?